# get selected value from dropdown on save

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am dynamically adding a row(with button and dropdown list) in table and each row is having edit save and delete button. onclick save button cell becomes non editable

```
function Save(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var isactive = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var id = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");

    isactive.html(id.children(':selected').val());
    id.html(id.children("input[type=text]").val());
}
```

when i click on save button the id field becomes non-editable but dropdown is editable so can anyone please tell me the right way to do that.

```
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var isactive = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var id = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    id.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+id.html()+"'/>");
 }
```

and on click edit it takes the value of id to set in textbox but how to do the same with dropdown please help...

Comment: does this help http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/348/

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Providing your HTML code might help. Also, when working with `<select>`, disabling needs to be done on the `<select>` element (not `<option>s`) and value can be get/set on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically Insert, Edit, Delete,Save Row in HTML table. 
Here i created a [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j24e6ggw/14/). Refer the code in jsfiddle.

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Table Management</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover  table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>    
        <td>Column 2</td> 
        <td>Edit row</td>
        <td>save</td>
        <td class='deleterow'>delete<div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>    
        <td>test1</td>  
        <td><a href='#' class='editrow'>edit</a></td>
        <td><a href='#' class='saverow'>save</a></td>
        <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>    
        <td>test2</td> <td><a href='#' class='editrow'>edit</a></td>
        <td><a href='#' class='saverow'>save</a></td> 
        <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

<hr><button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary addnewrow pull-right'>Add New <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

JS:

```
$(".deleterow").on("click", function(){
    var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("danger");
    $killrow.fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$(document).on('click',".saverow",function(){ 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var isactive = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var id = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
    isactive.html(isactive.children('select').val());
    id.html(id.children("input[type=text]").val()); 
});
$(document).on("click",".editrow", function(){ 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr 
    var isactive = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var id = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");      
    var prevVal = isactive.html();     
    isactive.html("<select class='seldom'/>");
    $('select.seldom')
         .append($("<option>A</option>")
         .attr("value","A")
         .text('A'));      
    $('select.seldom')
         .append($("<option>B</option>")
         .attr("value","B")
         .text('B')); 
    $('select.seldom option').each(function(){        
        if($(this).val() === prevVal){ // EDITED THIS LINE             
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");    
        }
    });
    id.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+id.html()+"'/>");
});
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent(); //tr
    console.log(par);
    var isactive = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var id = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    console.log(id)
    id.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+id.html()+"'/>");
 }

$(".addnewrow").on("click", function(){
    $('table tr:last').after("<tr><td data-qid='X'>NEW</td><td>NEW</td> <td><a href='#' class='editrow'>edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='saverow'>save</a></td><td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td></tr>");
});
```